# Button not aligned with input (due to padding of input)

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

The button below is not aligning with the input.
The input has to be on the same height as the button, though **the padding of the input seems to have a influence on the alignment!** The difference between padding-top and padding-bottom creates this shift of the button.

I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RMhm/10/ to show what I mean.

CSS:

```
.button {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 9px 23px;
    border:0;
}
.form  {
    width: 290px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
    height: 25px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
    padding-top: 15px;         <--- This padding
    padding-bottom: 0px;       <--- And this padding
}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="name" class="form" /> 
    <input class="button" type="submit">
```

Comment: do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/bneDU/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: middle` to both elements (button and input).

http://jsfiddle.net/3RMhm/3/

Comment: For people who are struggling, it says BOTH elements. I read over it the first time. But thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
vertical-align:middle;
margin-top: -5px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/3RMhm/2/

Answer (score 0):

In your `.form` class,just change `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` values to :

```
.form  {

    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;

}
```

Comment: Good point, though I want my text to have some padding inside the input